# How to overwrite a text file?

Tags: c, unix, printf, fopen

I'm coding on Unix.
I've a text file as output.
How can I overwrite the content every time I call a function?

Example:

```
functionA(){
    fp = fopen("text.txt",someflag);
    ...
    ...blabla
    ....
    fprintf(fp,"some new text");
}
```

So by calling `functionA`, I should have text.txt with new content.

For `someflag`, I've already tried `a`, `ab`, and `w+`, but none with the result I want. (`ab` appends new text, `w+` open the file, but `fprintf` doesn't work).
I'm using C on unix.

Comment: Just use `W` as flag.

Comment: What do you mean "fprintf doesn't work"?

Comment: "w" should do it.

Comment: It is possible that file is now written until you call `fclose`.

Comment: with "w" i can open the file but fprint doesn't write anything. With "ab" fprintf just appends, it not overwrites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag `"w"` should overwrite the existing file.

See [this documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) for details, specifically:

> The mode argument points to a string. If the string is one of the
>   following, the file shall be opened in the indicated mode. Otherwise,
>   the behavior is undefined.
>
> - r or rb: Open file for reading.
> - w or wb: Truncate to zero length or create file for writing.
> - a or ab: Append; open or create file for writing at end-of-file.
> - r+ or rb+ or r+b: Open file for update (reading and writing).
> - w+ or wb+ or w+b: Truncate to zero length or create file for update.
> - a+ or ab+ or a+b: Append; open or create file for update, writing at end-of-file.